# Is Pslam 22:16 a prophetic prophecy of the messiah?

Tags: messiah, prophecies

In Pslam 22:16 it talks about how he would be pierced for our transgressions, is this verse a prophetic verse that was fulfilled by Christ and if no how does Judaism interest this verse?

Comment: It's a mistranslation. כארי means "like a lion", not "they pierced me".

Comment: ... k/a/r doesn't mean "pierce" anywhere, and besides, the verse starts with comparing his opponents to dogs, so it makes sense (given the style of Psalms) to end with another animal analogy.

Comment: And the psalm doesn't mention the cause of the speaker's travail.

Comment: Anytime you have a question of "how does Judaism read the following verse" [whether it's a prooftext from Mathew, or any other verse and you're just curious], start with the Koren Jerusalem translation: https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.1?ven=The_Koren_Jerusalem_Bible&lang=en&with=Translations&lang2=en. It's free, quick, and easy.

Comment: There is a large movement of Christian apologists who are distancing themselves from these faulty translations. I will still say, given that Connor brought it up, that unless Connor is one a million, the odds of them believing that this is a bad translation are effectively zero